# Capturing Part of String

Tags: java

I want to capture part of a string and I know it involves some combination of substring, regex and matches, I'm having a really hard time putting together a decent solution.  Let's say I have a paragraph of text:

```
String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor [cookie:firstname] adipiscing elit.";
```

I would like to capture the text in-between the the : and ] above, "firstname" in this case (the cookie name could be variable length).  One way I suppose is using split:

```
str = str.split("\\cookie:")[1]");
```

then perhaps a str.replace to remove the training "]" - but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way of doing this.  I'm very new to regex, but haven't be successful getting what i need down.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below regex code: -

```
    String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor [cookie:firstname] adipiscing elit.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\[.*?:(.*?)\\].*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
firstname
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-liner:

```
String part = str.replaceAll(".*:(.*)].*", "$1");
```

The regex captures the whole input, which is replaced with the 1st group, which captures the part you want, effectively return just the part you want.

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor [cookie:firstname] adipiscing elit.";
    String part = str.replaceAll(".*:(.*)].*", "$1");
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Output:

```
firstname
```

Comment: You might want to add a leading `\\[` to the pattern, so that it only grabs the substring enclosed within brackets.

Comment: This worked but for some reason it caused the componet which held the text to reload.  Thanks, will be useful in my future exercises